# Google Earth Engine; Upload TFRecord via https://code.earthengine.google.com/ or command line fails

Tags: google-earth-engine

The Files: [Json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ehaQMwaDs45kKtdppx3n1RpCMOlrAqEv) [TFrecord](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GhBWHSxMX0kBu8jzuK4y-h8kfpW_w058)

The TFrecord is the **predict result** from a tensorflow model. Its a [1,1] Numpy array per patch and has been transformed to TFRecord by([like in this example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb)) :

`for predictionPatch in predictions:
    print('Writing patch ' + str(patches) + '...')
    predictionPatch = predictionPatch[
        x_buffer:x_buffer+KERNEL_SIZE, y_buffer:y_buffer+KERNEL_SIZE]

```
predictionPatch = predictionPatch[
    x_buffer:1, y_buffer:1]
# Create an example.
#example = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(predictionPatch).SerializeToString()

example = tf.train.Example(
  features=tf.train.Features(
    feature={
      'OC': tf.train.Feature(
          float_list=tf.train.FloatList(
              value=predictionPatch.flatten()))
    }
  )
).SerializeToString()


print("example",example)
print("type(example)",type(example))
#print("type(tf.io.parse_single_example(example))",type(tf.io.parse_single_example(example)))
# Write the example.

writer.write(example)
patches += 1
```

writer.close()`

**uploading the file via browser mask** https://code.earthengine.google.com/ works

[image]

but the ingestion results in :

[image]

changing the shape of the base date to [1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ehaQMwaDs45kKtdppx3n1RpCMOlrAqEv) and :

`predictionPatch = predictionPatch[
    x_buffer:1, y_buffer:1]`

to :

`predictionPatch = predictionPatch[
    0]`

results in a different error in the browser mask:

[image]

Manifests for TfRecord ingestion must have exactly one tileset with exactly one source.

**Uploading via earth engine on Linux:**

```
earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/AVHomefolder/XCeption_Carbon_KS1 gs://masterarbeit_bucket/test/XCeption_Carbon_KS1.TFRecord gs://masterarbeit_bucket/test/XCeption_Carbon_KS1.json
```

(the flag `--no-use_cloud_api` will start but will not upload)

throws some Dependencie Errors, but starts the Job. 
this error is retrieved from the browser mask:

[image]

reloading the TFRecord and using `.take(1)[0]` results in :

`<TakeDataset shapes: {OC: (1, 1)}, types: {OC: tf.float32}>
{'OC': <tf.Tensor: id=31, shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.24551529]], dtype=float32)>}`

using the same on the equivalent file from the [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=KxACnxKFrQ_J) results in similar Tensor :

`{'OC': <tf.Tensor: id=31, shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.]], dtype=float32)>}`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a workaround in rasterio, by using teh raw numpy predictions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import json
import rasterio
import sys 

path = os.path.join(sys.path[0],"path/to/pickled/numpy.pkl")
np_data = pickle.load( open( path, "rb" ) )

print("np_data",np_data)

jsonFile = os.path.join(sys.path[0],"path/to/json/mixer.json")
with open(jsonFile) as json_file:
    json_file = json_file
    mixer = json.load(json_file)
cols = int(mixer["patchesPerRow"])
rows = int(mixer["totalPatches"]/cols)

np_data = np_data.reshape((1,rows,cols))

print("np_data.shape",np_data.shape)

raster_path = os.path.join(sys.path[0],"path/to/geotiff.tif")
with rasterio.open(raster_path,'w',
    driver="GTiff",
    height=rows,
    width=cols,
    count=1,
    dtype="float32",
    crs=mixer["projection"]["crs"],
    transform=mixer["projection"]["affine"]["doubleMatrix"],
    nodata="nan") as dataset:
    dataset.write(np_data)
```